# Problem in concatenating two numpy image arrays. Throws error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have some real images in an image array and some fake images in another image array. I want to append the two numpy image arrays to train my CNN model. However `np.concatenate`produces the error `only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

That shape of my real images array is **(30938, 3,112,112)** and the shape of my fake images array is **(11372,3,112,112)** where the shape of each image is **(3,112,112)**

I have already tried,

`combined=np.concatenate(real,fake,axis=0)`

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just one mistake

```
combined=np.concatenate((real,fake),axis=0)
```